# How can I add random content (UIKit element) in collection view cell depending on incoming data with autoresizing?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In this function I made switch on incoming data type and I invoke function that add subview to my cell. At this moment I haven't data and I inserted stubs.

Method doesn't work, result is empty space after textview( haven't picture) ,and I dont know why, I add subview to my cell, in theory it must work. Now I don't use switch. I have cell height 350 , label height 50 and textview height 50 so for image/video I keep 250.
 Please help me with advice.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionNews",for: indexPath) as! NewsCell

        cell.personImage.image = UIImage(named: "welder.png")
        cell.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.addSubview(addImage(image : UIImage(named : "error.png")!, for: cell, at : indexPath ))

       //switch (contentArray[indexPath.row]){
       //case let image where image is String :
       //cell.addSubview(addImage(image : UIImage(named : "error.png")!, for: cell, at : indexPath ))
       //case let video where video is String :
       //break
       //default:
       //break
       // }

   return cell
}


func addImage(for cell : NewsCell, at index : IndexPath)->UIImageView{
    let testImg = UIImage(named: "error.png")

    let imageForCell = UIImageView(image: testImg)

    imageForCell.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth , UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]

    imageForCell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.textView.bounds.minX, y: cell.textView.bounds.maxY + 5, width: imageForCell.frame.origin.x, height: imageForCell.frame.origin.y)

    imageForCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    imageForCell.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return imageForCell

}
func addVideo () {

}
```

Comment: please check your code: you addImage function has a different signature from the one that you call in cellForItemAt..

Comment: func addImage(image : UIImage, for cell :NewsCell,at index : IndexPath)->UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

First: I see that function **addImage** is not declaring a UIImage as a parameter

Second: You're setting frame property for imageForCell wrong. You should do something like: (Supposing that you want your image below the textView)

```
var newFrame = cell.textView.frame
newFrame.y += 5
imageForCell.frame = newFrame
```

Comment: Problem was here : "imageForCell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.textView.bounds.minX, y: cell.textView.bounds.maxY + 5, width: imageForCell.frame.origin.x, height: imageForCell.frame.origin.y)"     In this params I used origin     : width: imageForCell.frame.origin.x, height: imageForCell.frame.origin.y. And you right, better use your method of frame assignment